# Calling trigger with specific user

Tags: content-hub

I have a trigger in `Content Hub`, and I want to initiate this trigger when an asset is updated. However, I want it to trigger only if the asset is modified by a specific user, for example, it should only trigger when the asset is updated by user `XYZ`.

I know I can add conditions to the triggers, and I want my condition to be 'Asset is modified by `XYZ`, but I couldn't find this condition. I can see a condition for `approved by`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After not receiving any response from anywhere, I created a `Sitecore ticket` for the issue and am sharing this here so that it can be helpful for others who might be encountering the same problem.

They confirmed that I won't be able to access this in the Trigger itself because it's not a value saved on the asset.

The alternate approach will be to access the `Context.TriggeringUserId` in the action script and apply the necessary conditions.